# grep: how to find ALL the lines between to expressions

Tags: regex, sed, grep

We have a HUGE file (numbers), we want to get ALL the lines between two expressions, e.g.,

```
232445 -9998.01 xxxxxxxxxx

234566 -9998.02 xxxxxxxxx

.

.

324444 -8000.012 xxxxxxx

344444 -8000.0 xxxx
```

and the expressions are `-9998.01` and `-8000.0`, so tried:

```
$ grep -A100000 '[0-9] -9998.[0-9]' mf.in | grep -B100000 '[0-9] -8000.[0-9]' mf.in > mfile.out
```

And this is OK ...ALL the lines between are get it... of course, 100000 is so big as to keept ALL the lines between... but if we are wrong? i.e., if there are more than 100000 between? How we can take ALL between without numeric specification after A and B ...

PD: I was unable to use sed with similar "[ ...]" expressions

PD2: the columns has more digits (here only 4 columns)

-1931076.0   -9998.96235   1.0002741998076021   0.0191476198569163

-1931075.0   -9998.95962   1.0000742544770280   0.0192495084654059

-1931074.0   -9998.95688   0.9998778097258081   0.0193725608470694

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` already has this functionality builtin using this expression:

`/regex1/,/regex2/ p`=>`p` command prints all lines that are present in between 2 lines(start line having `regex1` and end line having `regex2`(both inclusive in output)).

Here is an example wrt your file format:

```
$ cat file
124235 -69768.77 xxx
232445 -9998.01 xxxxxxxxxx
234566 -9998.02 xxxxxxxxx
12345 -124.66 xxxx
324444 -8000.012 xxxxxxx
344444 -8000.0 xxxx
344444 -7000.0 xxxx

$ sed -nr '/^[0-9]+\s-9998.[0-9]+\s/,/^[0-9]+\s-8000.[0-9]+\s/ p' file
232445 -9998.01 xxxxxxxxxx
234566 -9998.02 xxxxxxxxx
12345 -124.66 xxxx
324444 -8000.012 xxxxxxx
344444 -8000.0 xxxx
$
```

Comment: I found part. interesting sed,  +\s is "1 space" right?, but what about if regex 1,2 are reals with a lot of digits (-9981.0123343432..) :  9998.01[0-9] or +[0-9]?...doesn'tworks...

Comment: `a+b` means 1 or more occurrences of a followed by a single b, + means 1 or more and is applied to stuff present behind +

Comment: @distico modified my answer to match 1 or more digits.. Have a look

Comment: TVM @ritessht93, I figured out that this was the syntaxis... but doesn't works in my file... It's not the real file, It just have more decimals...

Comment: Can you post lines of your real file and desired output?

Comment: -1931076.0 -9998.96235  1.0002741998076021  0.0191476198569163 <br/>         -1931075.0 -9998.95962  1.0000742544770280  0.0192495084654059   <br/>   -1931074.0 -9998.95688  0.9998778097258081  0.0193725608470694 /

Comment: sorry some bugs (<br/>... the last line is -1931074.0  etc... they are ordered...there are a lot of other columns...

Comment: Hey its difficult to read it in comments.. Please edit your question and put the content over there

Comment: Can you post exact input data and required output.. I can't assume stuff

Answer (score 2):

With `awk`:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^-9998.01$/{p=1} p{print} $2 ~ /^-8000.0$/{p=0}' file
```

**Test:**

```
$ cat file 
232445 -9998.00 xxxxxxxxxx
232445 -9998.01 xxxxxxxxxx
234566 -9998.02 xxxxxxxxx
234566 -9998.03 xxxxxxxxx
234566 -9998.05 xxxxxxxxx
....
....
324444 -8000.011 xxxxxxx
324444 -8000.012 xxxxxxx
344444 -8000.0 xxxx
344444 -8000.1 xxxx

$ awk '$2 ~ /^-9998.01$/{p=1} p{print} $2 ~ /^-8000.0$/{p=0}' file 
232445 -9998.01 xxxxxxxxxx
234566 -9998.02 xxxxxxxxx
234566 -9998.03 xxxxxxxxx
234566 -9998.05 xxxxxxxxx
....
....
324444 -8000.011 xxxxxxx
324444 -8000.012 xxxxxxx
344444 -8000.0 xxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Well it might not be the best answer, but the easy fix for your command would be to use the file's number of lines as argument to `-A` and `-B`, so you're sure you cannot miss any lines:

```
NB_LINES=$(wc -l main.c | awk '{print $1}')
grep -A$NB_LINES '[0-9] -9998.[0-9]' mf.in | grep -B$NB_LINES '[0-9] -8000.[0-9]' mf.in > mfile.out
```

Though, tbh, in pure shell it's very likely I'd do something similar. Or I'd write a small python script, that would look like:

```
import re
LINE_RE = re.compile(r'[^ ]+ (-[0-9]+\.[0-9]+) .*')
with open('mf.in', 'r') as fin:
    with open('mf.out', 'w') as fout:
        for line in f:
            match = LINE_RE.match(line)
            if match:
                if float(match.groups()[0]) > -9998.0:
                    fout.write(line)
                elif float(match.groups()[0]) < -8000.0:
                    break
```

N.B.: *this script is just to expose the algorithmic idea, and being blindly coded and untested, it might need some tweaking to actually work*.

HTH

Comment: TVM!, yes ... but the search is even more complex ... and is cumbersome to get each line to find; better to identify the regex that you want..

Comment: Well, if you look at it, both the code and the grep are actually quite simple :-)